# Order results by alternating gender (male / female)

Tags: mysql

How can I order results by alternating best score by gender (#1 male, #1 female, #2 male, #2 female)

```
| uid   | gender | name      | score |
|     1 |   male |    robert |    96 |
|     2 | female |     linda |    38 |
|     3 | female |      kate |    99 |
|     4 |   male |      jack |    76 |
|     5 | female |      nina |    33 |
|     6 |   male |    pierre |   126 |
```

So I want male, female, male, female" then ordered by score.

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to sort by Score? ORDER BY Score?  Or do you want to order by gender?  Or do you want male, female, male, female then ordered by score?

Comment: Yes I "want male, female, male, female" then ordered by score

Answer (score 1):

This requires that you rank the scores per gender before sorting.  Here's a trick that uses MySQL user-defined variables to generate the ranking numbers dynamically in a derived table subquery:

```
SELECT rank, gender, score, name
FROM (
  SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN score, name, 
    @rank:=IF(@gender=gender,@rank+1,1) AS rank, @gender:=gender AS gender
  FROM (SELECT @gender:=NULL) AS _init 
  JOIN results
  ORDER BY gender, score DESC
) AS ranked_scores
ORDER BY rank ASC, gender DESC;
```

Tested on MySQL 5.6.12.

Output:

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+
| rank | gender | score | name   |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
|    1 | male   |   126 | pierre |
|    1 | female |    99 | kate   |
|    2 | male   |    96 | robert |
|    2 | female |    38 | linda  |
|    3 | male   |    76 | jack   |
|    3 | female |    33 | nina   |
+------+--------+-------+--------+
```

Here's a link to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91833/1/0) showing that the query above works.

Re your comment:

If you have any error, you need to be more specific and share the error message.  I can't guess what you see.

I'm not going to answer the question about sorting by name.

Comment: I have an error in your SQL syntax.
And if I want to order it by name?

Comment: @Amar At least you are putting forth 0 effort.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create two temp data sets (in this case temp tables), one for Male and one for Female.  Order by score.
Then iterate through each table, adding each line to your result set.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
    INTO maleOnly
WHERE gender = 'male'
ORDER BY score

SELECT *
FROM Table 
    INTO femOnly
WHERE gender = 'female'
ORDER BY score


DECLARE scores_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROM maleOnly
    FOR SELECT * FROM femOnly
OPEN scores_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM scores_cursor;
```

There are better ways of doing this, such as WITH (CTE), but this will give you an idea.